# How do I go about reinstalling Touch Wiz on a Sprint Galaxy S4

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-4

A recent up date for Cyanogenmod has left my phone stuck on the Samsung splash screen. So I need to get Touch Wiz back on it so I can use it. I don't care about losing any thing. How would I do this? All my contacts are online. And all my pictures are backed up. I really need this ASAP! please help me.

Comment: Sammoblile have the stock roms you can flash with odin and xda had tons of touchwiz based roms. Alternatively you could restore a nandroid backup image if you made one!  http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2265477